# Responsivness: blocks order + collapsible menu

Tags: routes, blocks

I'm using standard Responsive Bartik theme because of its responsive capabilities, but I have one issue. When smaller version of site is displayed (phone, tablet,..), navigation menu (first sidebar) jumps below the main content, but I want it to be on top of it - is this possible? How please?

Second question is, if it is possible to switch navigation menu (in phone or tablet version only) to some collapsed state? Like main menu switches itself (please see attached image)

[image: menu]

Thanks in advance

Lukas